# get raw text value of input type number

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, number-formatting

I have an input field with type="number" (because i want to validate my value with min/max, step).
When I enter a float value like '2.5', Chrome displays it in an language specifiy style (which can't be deactivated).
Now I want an other element (e.x. span) to display excatly the same value as displayed in the input.
Is there a possibility to get the displayed decimal separator?

Comment: You mean, you entered `2.5` and the input displays e.g `2,5`?

Comment: yes on a german OS Chrome displays it as 2,5, on others Chrome displays is as 2.5. And I don't know if there is another representation in an other language.